# How do I save code using loops while accessing json data?

Tags: javascript

I recently started my first programming project.
I started noticing that I use the same code over and over again, and would like to save that.

Here is an example:

```
   document.getElementById('Serie1').textContent = showtrend.tv_results[0].title ;
   document.getElementById('Serie1ID').textContent = "https://www.imdb.com/title/"+showtrend.tv_results[0].imdb_id ;
   document.getElementById('Serie1Year').textContent = showtrend.tv_results[0].year ;

   document.getElementById('Serie2').textContent = showtrend.tv_results[1].title ;
   document.getElementById('Serie2ID').textContent = "https://www.imdb.com/title/"+showtrend.tv_results[1].imdb_id ;
   document.getElementById('Serie2Year').textContent = showtrend.tv_results[1].year ;
```

I am basically adding the values I get in form of a json from my api to my site.

But how can I put all of this in a loop? It is like that for another 10 series, ant isn't very elegant

Would really appreciate the help

Comment: `showtrend.tv_results.length` will probably give you the length of the array you want to loop

Comment: What have you tried? What causes you problem? Writing a loop? Or concatenating a string and a variable? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you.

```
for (let i = 1; i < showtrend.tv_results.length; i++) {
    var name = 'Serie'+ i;
    document.getElementById(name).textContent = showtrend.tv_results[i-1].title ;
    document.getElementById(name+'ID').textContent = "https://www.imdb.com/title/"+showtrend.tv_results[i-1].imdb_id ;
    document.getElementById(name+'Year').textContent = showtrend.tv_results[i-1].year ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do:

**ECMAScript**

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://www.imdb.com/title/";

showtrend.tv_results.forEach(function (result, i) {
    let count = i + 1;
    document.getElementById(`Serie${count}`).textContent = result.title;
    document.getElementById(`Serie${count}ID`).textContent = BASE_URL + result.imdb_id;
    document.getElementById(`Serie${count}Year`).textContent = result.year;
});
```

**Vanilla JS**

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://www.imdb.com/title/";

for(var i = 1; i <= showtrend.tv_results.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('Serie' + i).textContent = result.title;
    document.getElementById('Serie' + i + 'ID').textContent = BASE_URL + result.imdb_id;
    document.getElementById('Serie' + i + 'Year').textContent = result.year;
});
```

In addition, maybe as your next challenge, try to get rid of these hard-coded elements in the list of "series" and make it dynamically created by pushing elements to an array in Javascript and populating a table or a list reading from this array. This will keep your code even more elegant.

Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Your section titled "ECMAScript" *is* vanilla javascript. You use template literals which was introduced in ES6 which came out in 2015.

Comment: That's why I have titled "ECMAScript" since template literals or string interpolation is only available for ECMAScript 2015 a.k.a. ES6 as you just said

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having predefined elements in your page that you have to fill, have one container element, and then iterate over the `tv_results` array and compile the information from each object into divs, or a table, and then insert that HTML as the `innerHTML` of the container.

This method will allow you to have as many movies in the data as you need.

```js
const json = '{"showtrend": {"tv_results": [{ "title": "Batman", "imdb_id": 1 },{ "title": "Ratman", "imdb_id": 2 }]}}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

// Pass in the parsed data
function getHTML(data) {

  // `map` over the tv_results array
  return data.showtrend.tv_results.map(obj => {
    
    // For each object in the iteration return a string of HTML.
    // This method uses a template literal, and adds
    // a data attribute to the outer div to identify the movie.
    return (
      `<div data-id="${obj.imdb_id}" class="movie">
         <div>${obj.title}</div>
         <div>${obj.imdb_id}</div>
       </div>`
    );

  // Finally join the array that `map` returns
  // and return that string
  }).join('');
}

// Cache the container element
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

// Call `getHTML` and add the returned HTML string
// to the `innerHTML` of the container
container.innerHTML = getHTML(data);
```

```css
.movie { margin-bottom: 0.5em; background-color: #efefef; padding: 0.2em; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)